# Using a ListView (and Adapter) as tabs in a wizard, but change color of already completed tabs

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I've created a fragment class with an `ArrayList<String>` (containing the items to be displayed in a ListView), which is actually "tab headings/labels". This works fine, and in the Adapter class I've created, I'm overriding `getView()` and can change the color of the selected item.  This works perfectly as well, even though it is not what I really want.

I am actually using this setup as a wizard to force the user through a series of steps.

So, say for instance there are 5 steps, and the user is at step 3 now, I want the 1st and the 2nd tabs' background color to be green (and the user can return to those screens), but the the 3rd tab's background color should be red (the step the user is at in the wizard), and the 4th and 5th tabs should be disabled (not be "clickable" by the user).

Is it possible to this?  Or actually everything is possible :)

Thanks guys,
Pieter

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert at all on the subject. But i believe that tabs that are not currently in the view are placed into the view recycler. I believe you can detect when a view is recycled and then you can change the color. Not sure if any of this helps but i hope some does

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with ListView, but you can do all of it with SlidingTabLayout [SlidingTabLayout example](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html). With this implementation you have full controll of colors of all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible in your getView() Check position and set text color according to your condition. Store in your adapter entity class a int to store color of textview and use it in getview